# Why does $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \lvert k^2 \sin (k^4) \rvert = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

For context: the question was if $x^2 y^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^4}) + 2$ converges on $2$ for $x \rightarrow 0$. My initial assumption was that this is false because if I use the sequence $(x_k, y_k) = (\frac{1}{k}, k^2)$ this works out as $\mathop{\lim}\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \lvert k^2 \sin(k^4) \rvert \overset{?}{=} 0$, which intuitively seems to diverge.

Yet the correct answer to the question was that it does indeed converge, and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20k%20-%3E%20infinity%20abs(k%5E2%20sin(k%5E4))) also says so. But [plotting the sequence with GeoGebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTUYQ.png) for the first 1000 elements shows a somewhat "random", yet growing sequence<sup>1</sup>.

So why does $\lvert k^2 \sin(k^4) \rvert$ sequence converge?

---

<sup>1</sup> Using the command `Sequence[(k, abs(k² sin(k⁴))), k, 1, 1000]`

Comment: Converges to $2$ as $x \to 0$ and $y$ does...what? If $y$ is held fixed then it does indeed converge to $2$, and this is usually what is understood when we write $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x,y)$. If you let it blow up then something else can happen.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says the limit equals "$0$ to $\infty$." What does that mean?

Comment: I think they mean "Fix $y$. Then $x^2y^2\sin(1/x^4)$ converges to $0$ as $x\to\infty$".

Comment: $y$ may blow up or be fixed. I only added the original question for context, I'm interested in the sequence $\lvert k^2 \sin(k^4)\rvert$.

Comment: The interesting question is whether $|k^2 \sin(k^4)|$ actually converges to $+\infty$. You shouldn't expect anything else. Wolfram Alpha's output there doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @Ian What does Wolfram Alpha's output mean? I don't expect the sequence to converge (to $+\infty$). I'm not sure of the correct English term, but I expect a divergence similar to that of $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (-1)^k$.

Comment: is y constant or does it depend on x?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam It is neither, both x and y are variables. But again, I'm interested in the sequence $\lvert k^2 \sin(k^4)\rvert$.

Comment: It can be proved that $\limsup_{k\to\infty} |k^2 \sin(k^4)| = +\infty$. So the real question is whether $\liminf_{k\to\infty} |k^2 \sin(k^4)| = +\infty$ or not. Now this looks quite a bold question to me. Notice that $$ k^2 |\sin (k^4)| \asymp k^6 \min_{p \in \Bbb{Z}} \left| \frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{p}{k^4} \right|$$ where $f(k) \asymp g(k)$ means that $c_1 g(k) \leq f(k) \leq c_2 g(k)$ for some absolute constants $c_1, c_2 > 0$. So the problem is really asking how $\frac{1}{\pi}$ can be well-approximated using only rational numbers of quartic denominator.

Comment: It means it doesn't converge to any real or any extended real and that all values from 0 to infty will always be reached as k -> infinity.  There will always be k > N where the value is 2.  There will always be k > N where value is 27 times the square roots of pi.  There will always be 0.  etc.

Answer (score 1):

The limit in the title doesn't converge. The function $f(x) = x^2 \sin (x^4)$ has $f(x_n) \to \infty$ for the sequence $x_n = \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n\right)^{1/4}$ and $f(y_n) \to 0$ for the sequence $y_n =\left(2\pi n\right)^{1/4}$.

Comment: In the post, $k$ is an integer.

Comment: The limit doesn't converge and what's more, Wolfram never said it did.  As $\pi$ is irrational $k$ integer isn't relevant.

Comment: @GEdgar: In that case, the limit still fails to converge, but it requires the result that the two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ are arbitrarily close to integers. That follows from the fact that the sequence $n\theta\mod{1}$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$ for $\theta$ irrational, which requires either a bit of clever approximation or some basic ergodic theory to prove. (In particular, getting an effective bound on $x^2 \sin (x^4)$ is a bit problematic.)

Answer (score 1):

In multi-variable calculus, whenever when we study what happens with a function in multiple variables when we operate (i.e. derivate, integrate, take a limit) with one variable, it is (usually) understood that all the other variables are fixed and should be treated as constants. This is the standard convention, and most likely it was explained/stated in your course.

If this usual convention was used in your class, then the question asks "If we fix $y$, then does $x^2 y^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^4}) + 2$ converges to $2$ when $x \to 0$?". And the answer is yes."

**Extra comment**
Also note that if you calculated at any point an integral of the form
$$\int_0^1 xy dx $$
you actually used the convention that $y$ must be fixed. And if you set the corresponding Riemann sum for this integral, you end up with a limit of the form 
$$\lim_{n} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}y$$
which exactly as in your example does not exists if you take $y=n \to \infty$, yet you know how to calculate integrals of this type. Same argument applies for derivatives.

This convention for integrals and derivatives (i.e. derivate/integrate wrt one variable and treat the rest as constants) is actually equivalent with this convention for limits: to calculate $\lim_x f(x,y)$ fix $y$ and calculate the limit by $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming (albeit without authority) that when Wolfram says $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f(k) = 0$ to $\infty$, that means:

For any $N \in \mathbb R$ and any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $a \in [0,\infty)$ there is a $k > N$ so that $|f(k) - a| < \epsilon$.

i.e. $f(x)$ not only doesn't converge to any real or extended real value, it also oscillates between all non-negative limits.

For $f(k) = k^2\sin k^4$ this is clearly true.  $\sin k^4$ oscilates between all values between $0$ and $1$ and so $f(k)$ which is continuous will oscilate between all values between $0$ and all  $x < \lim k^2 = \infty$.

Comment: The last statement is less clear to me. Indeed, one can prove that if $\alpha$ is large enough then $k^{\alpha} \sin (k^4) \to \infty$ using the fact that the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is finite. Excluding the possibility that $\alpha$ can be pushed all the way down to $2$ would require quite non-trivial argument.

Comment: Perhaps.  I wasn't taking k is an integer into account.  Still, it very clearly does not converge and wolfram never said it did.